# How to select read/write time and again?

Tags: linux, c, select

This program only waits one time and I don't understand why. Actually, I don't think this question should be put on hold as off-topic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  fd_set set;
  struct timeval timeout;
  int rv;
  char buff[100];
  int len = 100;
  int filedesc = open( "/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR );
  int filedesc1 = filedesc + 1;

  timeout.tv_sec = 5;
  timeout.tv_usec = 10000;
  while(1) {
    printf("begin:\n");
    FD_ZERO(&set); /* clear the set */
    FD_SET(filedesc, &set); /* add our file descriptor to the set */
    rv = select(filedesc1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if(rv == -1)
      perror("select\n"); /* an error accured */
    else if(rv == 0)
      printf("timeout\n"); /* a timeout occured */
    else
      read( filedesc, buff, len ); /* there was data to read */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Select` manpage:

> On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not
>   slept; most other implementations do not do this. (POSIX.1-2001 permits either behavior.)

After the first timeout occurs, your `timeout` variable has been updated to reflect the amount of time remaining to sleep, which is 0, because it waited for the entire 5.01s.

Notice how the last argument to `select` is not declared `const`.

If you want it to wait for 5.01s again on subsequent times, you need to move this code:

```
timeout.tv_sec = 5;
timeout.tv_usec = 10000;
```

...inside the `while` loop.